# Python Scrapy not iterating selectorlist

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract data using scrapy (python 3). This is the structure.

[image]

These two tables are extracted as:

```
tables = response.xpath('//div[@class="w3-margin-top"]/table')
```

Table[0] has 10  tags and table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIxAb.png) has approx 40  tags.

When I try to extract rows while iterating,

```
 for table in tables:
    rows = table.xpath('.//tbody/tr')
    print(len(rows))
```

I get result as 10 and 0 respectively.

Comment: browser may shows `<tbody>` tag but real HTML may not have it so better never use `<tbody>`- `.xpath('.//tr')`. If page uses javascript to add rows then you may not get them.

Comment: Try selecting tables with `response.css('table.w3-table')` instead then find the rows as you did here

Comment: thanks guys. That was the issue. Chrome inspect was adding the tbody and was missing in the original src. Used css to extract tr and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

As per said in comments Chrome code inspector shows some sort of normalized code with JavaScript executed already, which can significantly affect the code you see.

To see reliable data for scraping check raw file source with `Ctrl+U`